# i have loaded liferay in eclipse while deploying err msg

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay

I'm new to liferay.

I've added liferay to Eclipse Java EE IDE : **Version: Indigo Service Release 2:** with liferay tomcat server

Liferay home page was opened up...
I've created a new portlet in liferay to print " **hello**" with portlet name: " **portel_exp1** "

but via deploying the portlet I've got an err msg as given below....

```
BUILD FAILED
F:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\build-common-plugin.xml:651:
 The following error occurred while executing this line:
F:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\build-common.xml:95:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main :
   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: it seems that its JRE problem. try to compile code with new version

Comment: Most probably, you'll have to edit project properties. Right click your project and go to properties. Can you tell us what's the 'targeted runtime', and give us a screenshot from 'Java Build Path'.

Comment: Never used Liferay but usually these types of errors are a result of different versions of jars hence the different class versions. How about you try following this again and get the jars from one place - http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-tomcat-7-0

Answer (score 0):

To compile it with new version (In Eclipse)

```
Go to window -> preferences -> java - > inside java select compiler - > check your compiler compliance level(select appropriate level i.e 1.6)
```

HTH

Comment: i have done that aftr that d same err msg comes.. i ve restarted my system n chkd..

Comment: can you check your build path of project? rightclick on project -> build path - > configure build path ->  JRE ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post but i had the same problem and i fixed it by making sure that java compiler for the project and eclipse java compiler are the same version. you can check your eclipse java compiler in preferences >> java >> compiler, and you can check your project compiler by right clicking on your project and selecting properties >> java compiler.
make sure both use the same JRE version.